# .net, MS Access, Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Source Error:

Line 168:      comm.Parameters.Add(param);

Line 169:

Line 170:      int totalCount = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

Line 171:      conn.Close();

Line 172:

I keep getting the error message "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" when the code run to the following method:

```
protected void makeOrder()
{
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
  conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["onlineStoreConnString"].ConnectionString;
  conn.Open();
  OleDbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
  comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Order (UserID, ProductID, OrderDate, ProductQty, IsCart) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

  OleDbParameter param;
  param = comm.CreateParameter();
  param.DbType = DbType.String;
  param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  param.Value = Int32.Parse(Session["LoggedInId"].ToString());
  comm.Parameters.Add(param);

  param = comm.CreateParameter();
  param.DbType = DbType.String;
  param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  param.Value = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
  comm.Parameters.Add(param);

  param = comm.CreateParameter();
  param.DbType = DbType.String;
  param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  param.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
  comm.Parameters.Add(param);

  param = comm.CreateParameter();
  param.DbType = DbType.String;
  param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  param.Value = Int32.Parse(txtQty.Text);
  comm.Parameters.Add(param);

  param = comm.CreateParameter();
  param.DbType = DbType.String;
  param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  param.Value = true;   
  comm.Parameters.Add(param);

  int totalCount = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
  conn.Close();

}
```

The database is MS Access, and the data type of the attributes are 
UserID:     Number,

ProductID:  Number,

OrderDate:  Long Text,

ProductQty: Number

IsCart:     Yes/No

I have been sticking in this bug for couple hours, any can help me find it? Thanks.

Comment: `Order` is a reserved keyword. Surround it with double-quotes or backticks (if using mysql)

Comment: The DBMS is MS Access

Comment: Thank you! It is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Order` is *very likely* to be a reserved word in your database engine, since it's a keyword in SQL queries.  You need to enclose your identifiers to prevent them from being mistaken as keywords.  Depending on your database engine, it might be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (UserID, ProductID, OrderDate, ProductQty, IsCart) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

or this:

```
INSERT INTO `Order` (UserID, ProductID, OrderDate, ProductQty, IsCart) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

or perhaps even something else (again, depending on your database).

Technically you can (and may even want to) enclose all of your identifiers, for a variety of reasons:

```
INSERT INTO [Order] ([UserID], [ProductID], [OrderDate], [ProductQty], [IsCart]) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This could be for consistency, for protection against further ambiguity (unlikely, but possible), or even for a very slight performance improvement in the query parsing (which could be important in aggregate for high-volume situations).